# Почему в плагине Contact form 7 Вордпресс выходит ошибка

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

### В поле "От кого" когда пишешь домен сайта выходит ошибка.(Использован некорректный синтаксис почтового адреса.)

Моя форма:

```html
<div class="row">
  <p class="col-lg-12">[text* First name placeholder ="Ваше имя"]</p>
  <p class="col-lg-12">[text* Your email placeholder ="Ваш email"]</p>
  <p class="col-lg-12">[text* Your phone number placeholder ="Ваш номер телефона"]</p>
  <p class="col-lg-auto">[submit class:btn class:btn-color-white"Отправить"]</p>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что это за почтовый адрес такой? Там как минимум еще собачка перед этим всем должна быть и еще какой-то набор символов перед собачкой.

Comment: Если не понятно, что такое *почтовый адрес*, то достаточно перейти по ссылке чтобы узнать, что тут нужно вписать **емейл**-адрес, При чем он должен быть в домене сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую вписать вот так:
`[_site_title] <wordpress@yoursite.ru>`

А еще можно вот в документации посмотреть: https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/

Comment: интересный источник «документации» для wordpress.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это документация к плагину который используется

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin можно [по коду посмотреть](https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/contact-form-template.php#L41), на вход идёт название сайта, опционально, и e-mail. E-mail обязателен и должен быть в формате.